# How to call a Ts function in angular without Ngif or click function?

Tags: angular

i need to call a ts function without ngif or click function in html using angular.
I need to check the function and bind those values in html.Since it has 3 condition i could not able to use general ngif in html.Please give me suggestions

```
<td>
checkEmployee(Employee)
{{employeeresult}}

</td>




 checkEmployee(Employee){
  if (employee.result=='Excellent'){
    this.employeeresult='Approve';
    
  }
  else if (employee.result=='Good'){
    this.employeeresult='Withheld';
  }
  else{
    this.employeeresult='Reject';
  }
```

Comment: just use return statement

Comment: @NidhinKumar problem i have is with the html.It is not recognising it as a method .Even inside Div tag if we provide in a ngif statment only it considers it as a method

Comment: hello @viswanath check my post below so you will get idea about it if my answer helpful than voteup and accepted best answer so other can find easy ;)

Answer (score 2):

My Answer is different from other implementations because I would suggest you to use a **pipe** instead of calling the method in your **template** :

```
<td>
{{ employee | employeePipe }}
</td>
```

And this how your **epmloyee-pipe.ts** looks :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'employeePipe'
})
export class employeePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(employee: EmployeeModel): string {
    switch (employee.result) {
      case 'Excellent' : return 'Fonctionnel';
      case  'Good': return 'Technique';
      default:
              return 'Reject'
        break;
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: the best practice is to use pipe because it triggers whenever your value changes. If you use a method for returning a value your method is called unwantedly many times. I would say its best to use Pipes.

Answer (score 0):

You could return it and bind the function in the template like this:

```
<td>
{{checkEmployee(employee)}}
</td>




 checkEmployee(employee){
  if (employee.result=='Excellent'){
    return 'Approve';
  } else if (employee.result=='Good'){
    return 'Withheld';
  } else {
    return 'Reject';
  }
```

Another way to do this is by using a pipe. Using pipes would be more performant compared to a function call.

Comment: As William Juan mentioned I would suggest use to use a pipe instead of calling the function in template for some performance reason !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `return` for getting label from the condition.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let employee of employeess">
    {{checkEmployee(employee)}}
</div>
```

**TS**

```
employeess = [{ result: 'Good' }, { result: '' }];

checkEmployee(employee) {
  if (employee.result == 'Excellent') {
    return 'Approve';
  } else if (employee.result == 'Good') {
    return 'Withheld';
  } else {
    return 'Reject';
  }
}

// output 
   Withheld
   Reject
```

You can play with [my code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bzym8f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).